# How should a unit test deal with expected and unexpected exceptions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Should it pass the test when the expected exception takes place?
Should it fail the test when an unexpected exception arises?
Is it redundant to handle the exception since it'll fail the test and therefore act as a test?

Comment: IMO, yes, yes, and yes.

Comment: The posts for answers are great, but it's often forgotten to mention the ExpectedException @Rule ;-)

Answer (score 11):

### Test Expected Exceptions

You have to add the `expected` attribute with the expected exception, so the test will pass if the specified exception is thrown. Otherwise, it will fail.

For example:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void cannotConvertNulls() {
    service.convert(null);
}
```

or...

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)  
public void divisionWithException() {  
    int i = 1/0;
}
```

[Documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) says:

> The Test annotation supports two optional parameters. The first,
>   expected, declares that a test method should throw an exception. If it
>   doesn't throw an exception or if it throws a different exception than
>   the one declared, the test fails.

### Test Timemouts

Just to let you know, you can also test timeouts.

> The second optional parameter, timeout, causes a test to fail if it
>   takes longer than a specified amount of clock time (measured in
>   milliseconds). The following test fails:

```
@Test(timeout=100) 
public void infinity() {
   while(true);
}
```

Hope to help

Comment: I never knew you could do this in JUnit, awesome

Comment: @ZackNewsham yes, it's very nice. Btw, you can also use @Test(timeout=100) that causes a test to fail if it takes longer that the timeout. It is very useful to do performance unit test

Comment: that latter one also sounds great, I've been working on tests for an SMPP engine that has issues with timeout. I guess I should keep more upto date on the Java docs!

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks for the +1, really appreaciate it. Well, for me the important matter is to help the community not only the OP

Comment: @Fede i threw a few your way :) I know what you mean.. but on the other side a part of helping the community is keeping questions clean and also accepting answers to each question to help others know what is the correct answer or the one that fixed / solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

For expected exceptions there are really nice ways to do this with JUnit:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullPointerExceptionIsThrown() {
    ArrayList emptyList;
    emptyList.size(); //or add, remove etc. 
}
```

The above test in JUnit would **pass** because it was declared with the @Test annotation that the test method should expect that a null pointer exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If the test is to expect a particular exception will arise with certain data, then **yes**, it should **pass** if that particular exception is thrown.

If the test is to expect a particular exception will arise with certain data, **or** there is no expectation of an exception, then **yes**, it should **fail** if any exception outside of expected is thrown.

**Do not handle the thrown exceptions yourself** unless you have to (and if you have to, that's a test smell - revisit why you're handling exceptions).  The best way to indicate to JUnit that you expect an exception is to use the `expected` field on the `@Test` annotation.

For example, let's say you were testing a Roman numeral converter, and said that anything not in the normal Roman numerals was an illegal argument (namely, P).

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void method_takesIllegalArgument_throwsIllegalArgumentException() {
    convertRomanNumeralToNumber("PXL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are part of your API, and sometimes explicitly so. As such, you should document the exceptions that your code may throw, and write tests to ensure that they are upheld.

`@Test(expected = ThisException.class)` is an excellent place to start, if you have JUnit4 and are writing a method that will `throw new ThisException(...)`. Note the value here of picking the most appropriate exception: If you get lazy and use `expected = Exception.class`, your code would accept it if you change to `throw new ThatException(...)` instead. Your non-exception code should pass if and only if no exceptions are thrown (which JUnit will enforce for you), and your tests should carefully specify exactly which exception to expect so they can fail if and only if that specific exception is thrown.

As [dhiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16193/dhiller) noted in the comments, the [ExpectedException rule](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) is also a very good choice for JUnit4, and allows further inspection of the thrown exception:

```
@Rule ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test public void yourTest() {
  // This is for demonstration. Don't actually verify the exact exception message
  // unless you want to have to update your test if the text ever changes.
  expectedException.expectMessage("Error 743: Toilet paper missing.");
  systemUnderTest.doStuff();
}
```

But if you really want to check state after catching an exception, the best way to go is JUnit3-style:

```
@Test public void yourTest() {
  try {
    systemUnderTest.doStuff();
    fail("ThisException expected.");
  } catch (ThisException expected) {
    assertEquals(743, expected.getErrorNumber());
  }

  // In both @Test(expected=...) and ExpectedException code, the
  // exception-throwing line will be the last executed line, because Java will
  // still traverse the call stack until it reaches a try block--which will be
  // inside the JUnit framework in those cases. The only way to prevent this
  // behavior is to use your own try block.

  // This is especially useful to test the state of the system after the
  // exception is caught.

  assertFalse(systemUnderTest.hasToiletPaper());
}
```

Another library that claims to help here is [catch-exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/); however, as of May 2014, the project appears to be in maintenance mode (obsoleted by Java 8), and much like Mockito catch-exception can only manipulate non-`final` methods.